# Building Jar with dependency of Akka

Tags: java, maven, ant, jar, akka

I'm trying to implement akka in java project with eclips. It runs fine when i run it from eclips but when I create and run the runnable jar from eclips, it generate error.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'akka.remote.log-received-messages'
```

And my dependency of Akka are

```
akka-actor_2.10,akka-remote_2.10
```

The issue is that there are configuration files named as reference.conf in both jar, so when exporting jar overwrite earlier instances of the configuration file with later instances.
we need to to append all resource.conf files into a single file instead of overwriting.

there is a solution in Maven plugin configuration

```
<transformers>
  <transformer
   implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
   <resource>reference.conf</resource>
  </transformer>     
</transformers>
```

But i need similar configuration in ANT build.
Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Was my anwwer useful? If you up-vote and accept useful answers people will be more motivated to help you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ant concat task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/concat.html)

```
<concat destfile="all-resources.conf" append="true">
    <filelist dir="${resource.dir}" files="**/resource.conf"/>
</concat>
```

Comment: hi, what i include as ${resource.dir}. resource.conf files are inside akka jar.

Comment: @Munees Majid in this case you may unjar it using unzip ant task

Comment: Ok fine. is there any way for create jar (ant jar task) by concating akka reference.conf?

Comment: You concatenate files with concat task and then create a jar with jar task.

Comment: @ Oleg Pavliv   when unjar it using unzip ant task the files with same name reference.conf may overwrite another.

Comment: @Munees Majid you unzip each file into a different directory